# pygame surface.fill() がうまく動かない

Tags: python, pygame

pygameについて以下のようなプログラムを書きました。

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT

# globals
WINDOW_SIZE = (400,300)
WINDOW_TITLE = "Pygame Count"

def main() :
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption(WINDOW_TITLE)
    sysfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None,36)
    counter = 0
    while True :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT :
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        counter += 1
        surface.fill((255,255,255))
        count_image = sysfont.render(
            "count is {0}".format(counter),True,(0,0,0))
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

このプログラムを実行すると以下のようなことが起こります。

- surface.fill() で背景の色が変更されない
- sysfont.render() で文字の色が変更されていない

（実行環境:macOS Mojave,python 3.7.0,pygame 1.9.4）
背景色はMojaveのダークモードの基本色です。（ライトモードに変更したところ基本色である白色になりますが、色の変化は見られませんでした）

また、以下を参考にテストしてみましたが、色の変化は見られませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873581/pygame-surface-fill-not-working

Comment: 作成した `count_image` を `blit` 等で描画していないのではないですか？

Answer (score 1):

Windowsでは、こんな感じで、数値を変えれば色は変わって見えます。

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT

# globals
WINDOW_SIZE = (400,300)
WINDOW_TITLE = "Pygame Count"

def main() :
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
    pygame.display.set_caption(WINDOW_TITLE)
    sysfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None,36)
    counter = 0
    while True :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT :
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        counter += 1
        surface.fill((255,255,255))  # = > この数値を変えれば背景色は変わります。
        count_image = sysfont.render(
            "count is {0}".format(counter),True,(0,0,0))  # = > 同じく文字色が変わります。
        surface.blit(count_image, (64,64))  # = > 文字を描画するために挿入しています。
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(100)  # = > カウンタが変わったことを目視する時間のディレイを挿入。

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

1件だけ、pythonの版数を明確に指定すれば動いた記事がありました。
しかし、他何件かは未解決のようです。
[Screen.Fill() in Pygame isn't changing the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53878082/9014308)

[Why are my pygame images not getting the alpha set after changing from windows to mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20920273/9014308)
[Pygame: display.update() does not update until after clock delay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50219028/9014308)
[pygame: window changing color after minimize and restore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20791417/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問する際に、なぜか写し忘れたのですがblitやpygame.time.Clock()などでdelayはしていました。Windowsでは確かに色が変化しますね。（Mac OSでは・・・）

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6 です。自身も"ゲームを作りながら楽しく学べるPYTHONプログラミング"で同じ問題が出たのですが、

PYTHON 3.7.3 (brew install)
pygame 2.0.0.dev1

を指定してインストールしたら　解決しましたよー。